# Fixed navigation inside absolute main element

Tags: css

I have a main element with position absolute so i can create the masthead swallow page effect.

My start screen is the masthead with full page height and as you scroll down the main element swallows the masthead.

My problem is that i want to position fix my navigation inside main element, but when i 
`position:fixed;top:0px` my section.header its not working

**EDITED**: I just added a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqkD6/) to explain myself a bit more

```
div.container{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.flexbox .masthead {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.flexbox main[role=main] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="masthead">...
    </header>
    <main role="main" id="content">
      <section class="header">...nav...</section>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle please, what do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like you want the menu to move with the main element when it scrolls up, for that you need to use position:absolute; not position:fixed;

Using position:fixed; will literally fix the menu in one spot in the window and it will not move at all.

I think this is what you are asking for: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hvNg2/1/)

I just started from scratch with the CSS. The Main content scrolls up from the bottom and covers the "masthead" and the navigation is at the top of the main content.

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <header class="masthead">
        <h1>Masthead</h1>
        <p>Scroll Down</p>
    </header>
    <main role="main" id="content">
        <section class="header">
            <ul>
                <li>nav |</li>
                <li>nav |</li>
                <li>nav |</li>
                <li>nav |</li>
                <li>nav |</li>
                <li>nav |</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
         <h1>Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ispum dolor sit amet consectular adapising elite.</p>
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    html {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.contatiner {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
.masthead {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-100;
    top:45%;
    bottom:45%;
    left:40%;
    right:40%
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top:90%;
    padding:50px 20px 100% 20px;
    left:30px;
    right:30px;
    background:#fff;
}
.header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.header ul li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I must say your code is much smaller than mine. So first thanks for that. Second, i need the navigation to stick on scroll on top. I added a fiddle to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by stick on scroll on top... do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VtBhn/

Comment: Yes, exactly. But 
1) i need the navigation inside main element
2) must "stick on top" when the user scrolls down

Comment: So you want the navigation bar to ride up to the top of the page and then stay there?